# pthread_sigmask:unusual behavior

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, signals

I am working with Linux and trying code related to signal handling.Following code i am trying but i am not able to understand the behavior of this code.

```
/**Globally declared variable**/

    time_t start, finish;
    struct sigaction sact;
    sigset_t new_set, old_set,test;
    double diff;

/**Function to Catch Signal**/
void catcher( int sig )
{
    cout<< "inside catcher() function\n"<<endl;
}


void Initialize_Signalhandler()
{

    sigemptyset( &sact.sa_mask );
    sact.sa_flags = 0;
    sact.sa_handler = catcher;
    sigaction( SIGALRM, &sact, NULL );

    sigemptyset( &new_set );
    sigaddset( &new_set, SIGALRM );

}


/**Function called by thread**/
void *threadmasked(void *parm)
{

/**To produce delay of 10sec**/
        do {
         time( &finish );
         diff = difftime( finish, start );
    } while (diff < 10);

    cout<<"Thread Exit"<<endl;

}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    Initialize_Signalhandler();

    pthread_t a;
    pthread_create(&a, NULL, threadmasked, NULL);

    pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_set, &old_set);

    time( &start );
    cout<<"SIGALRM signals blocked at %s\n"<< ctime(&start) <<endl;


    alarm(2); //to raise SIGALM signal


/**To produce delay of 10sec**/
        do {
         time( &finish );
         diff = difftime( finish, start );
    } while (diff < 10);


return( 0 );
}
```

Even thoght i am  using " pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_set, &old_set)". it is not blocking the signal. But if i remove "pthread_create(&a, NULL, threadmasked, NULL);"  its working fine and blocking the signal. And another thing i have observed here is if i change  **pthread_sigmask** to **sigprocmask** behavior remains same.

Answer (score 2):

Threads inherit the signal mask from the thread they are created by.

So as your code calls `pthread_sigmask()` **after** it calls `pthread_create()` the the freshly created thread does not have its signal mask modified.

Change your code like so, do make things work as you expect:

```
...

pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_set, &old_set);

pthread_t a;
pthread_create(&a, NULL, threadmasked, NULL);

...
```

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion... But i am raising the signal from main thread and i am updating its ""pthread_sigmask"" so why it is not able to block the signal and Another thing if i use pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_set, &old_set) in Thread function ie.threadmasked its blocking the signal

Comment: According to what i understood pthread_sigmask change  the calling thread's signal mask, regardless of the number of threads in the process.But here its changing the behaviour of Parent Thread..

Comment: The signal raise by alarm is sent to the current process. It is left to the OS which thread will handle the signal. As you blocked signals for the main thread, but didn't for one explicitly created, the alarm signal is handled by the latter. If you apply the changes I proposed the alarm signal would not be caugth.

Comment: ok...Thanks got the point...Here in this case alarm signals is sent to child thread. what i understood is that pthread_sigmask is used to enable or disable the signal for that particular thread who is calling pthread_sigmask() and will not reflect in any other thread. CORRECT me if i am wrong

Comment: @vinaypatel: You are correct. But keep in mind the signal masks are inherited by threads, as mentioned in my answer.